# Adding multiple searchable files to one Solr-index-document

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Is there a way or best practice to add more than one file (e.g. 2 pdfs and 1 doc) into one solr-index-doc using the extract handler? The result when querying should look somehow like this:

```
<result name="response">
 <str name="id">123</str>

  <doc>
   <arr name="attr_content">
    content of pdf-1
   </arr>
  </doc>

  <doc>
   <arr name="attr_content">
    content of pdf-2
   </arr>
  </doc>

  <doc>
   <arr name="attr_content">
    content of doc-1
   </arr>
  </doc>

</result>
```

In my java application I am adding files to the Solr-Index like that which adds only one file:

```
ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
up.addFile(new File("c:\\document1.pdf"));
up.setParam("literal.id", solrId);
up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
solr.request(up);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just allows one file to be attached as an attachment.
Solr does allow zip files to be indexed ([patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2416)), which would index the contents for the files.
So you can package the files into a zip and feed it Solr, which would be indexed as a Single document.